# Proving global existence of solutions for system of ODE's?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lipschitz-functions

$x'(t) =  |y|, x(0) = 1$

$y'(t) = |x|, y(0)  = 1$

How to show that the system has a global existence $\forall t \in (-\infty, \infty)$?

As $|y|,|x|$ are continuous over all of the real lines, so we can say that the solutions exist!, but I think it guarantees us the local existence if so how i can prove for global existence? Also the partial derivative $\frac{\partial{f_{1}}}{\partial{x}},\frac{\partial{f_{2}}}{\partial{y}}  = 0$ implying boundedness and hence Lipschitz, ?

But is this correct? any stronger argument I should give?

Comment: $x(t)=y(t)=e^{t}$ is a global solution.

Comment: Nice, but any precise way of proving the global existence or providing a solutions which exist globally would do?

Comment: To prove the existence of a solution you only have to give on example. It is precise and rigorous to say that a global solution exists because of this example. If you are thinking more general DE's for which you want to prove existence of a solution you will have to specify what kind of DE's you are considering.

Comment: Got it!!, thanks that was a clever observation I would say!

Comment: Any comments on the Lipschitz case as made in the question?

Comment: I am unable to understand your question involving partial derivatives. Can you rephrase it?

Comment: boundedness of partial derivatives of $f_{1},f_{2} ($ functions on the RHS of the ODE's) implying Lipschitz, so can that be used for global existence of solutions to the system of ODE's?

Comment: More generally, you might look at  [Grönwall's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sketch**: Observe
\begin{align}
\left|\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}\log|x(t)^2+y(t)^2| \right|=\left|\frac{x(t)x'(t)+y(t)y'(t)}{x(t)^2+y(t)^2}\right| \leq \frac{2|x(t)||y(t)|}{x(t)^2+y(t)^2} \leq 1
\end{align}
then we have that
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2}|\log|x(t)^2+y(t)^2||  \leq \frac{1}{2}\log 2+ \frac{1}{2}\int^t_0\left|\frac{d}{d\tau}\log|x(\tau)^2+y(\tau)^2| \right|\ d\tau \leq t+\frac{1}{2}\log 2.
\end{align}
Hence it follows
\begin{align}
x(t)^2+y(t)^2= \exp\left(\log|x(t)^2+y(t)^2| \right) \leq \exp\left(|\log|x(t)^2+y(t)^2|| \right) \leq 2e^{2t}.
\end{align}
Since $x(t), y(t)$ are bounded for every finite interval $[0, T]$ then the solution can be extended to a bigger time interval. Hence $x(t), y(t)$ have  global solutions.

Comment: $\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2}|\log|x(t)^2+y(t)^2||  \leq \frac{1}{2}\log 2+ \frac{1}{2}\int^t_0\left|\frac{d}{d\tau}\log|x(\tau)^2+y(\tau)^2| \right|\ d\tau \leq t+\frac{1}{2}\log 2.
\end{align}$, I am not getting how to get this??, like how the first inequality?

Comment: The first inequality comes from Fundamental theorem of calculus and the above inequality.

Comment: Like why log(2) ?

Comment: $\log(x(0)^2+y(0)^2) = \log (1+1) = \log 2$

Comment: I think inequality is reversed as in FTOC, $F(b) - F(a) \geq \int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx$ ?

Comment: FTOC is equality.

Comment: YES then why there is an inequality in t he answer??

Comment: Please spend sometime to think about my solution.

Comment: Yes, I understood your solution completely, thanks , the answer is nice!!